# How to achieve this in my office network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan, squid

Here is my existing office network.
[image]

I have setup Squid proxy server on one of my PC.

How do I have all devices connect thru this proxy server instead of the router.

NOTE: All PCs are connected to each other in Wireless LAN.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `transparent proxy` setup (i.e. without having to set proxy setting on every client) - it depends on your router. Not every consumer grade router would allow this. Take a look at this [DD-WRT transparent proxy guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy) to see what's involved.